# UIPageViewController delay page change animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, delay, uipageviewcontroller

I am developing an application that makes use of a UIPageViewController. I noticed that if I change multiple pages too quickly, it causes several problems at runtime.

Is there a way to set a delay (such 2 or 3 milliseconds) between two page changes?
Thanks in advance.

****************** *DETAILED ANSWER* **********************

The solution is this:

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{

    if(completed) {
        [pageViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [self performSelector:@selector(enableUserInteraction) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    }
}

-(void)enableUserInteraction{
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: you have accepted this answer. have you found where exactly you want to put userInteraction = NO ?

Comment: I'll modify the question adding the answer :)

Comment: thanks a lot but I have already done same using Gabriel's idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your animation block, set userInteraction = NO until the animation finishes. This mean that the user will not be able to interact with the screen and thus change the page until it finishes animating.

Comment: There is not an animation block beacuse the animation code is hidden in the UIPageViewController Class. Furthermore I can't tell the controller userIntractionEnabled = NO when I'm trying to browse the page, the action won't be accepted..

Answer (score 0):

I put it in the **pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:** and used **dispatch_after**. With this solution the user cannot swipe quickly 2-3 times like in 
pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)pendingViewControllers {
pageViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    pageViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

});

}
```